# What exactly is the CTMU?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

http://www.ctmu.org/

Recently I read about this guy with a really high IQ, Chris Langan, who crafted an ultimate theory of reality - CTMU, Cognitive-Theoretical Model of the Universe - which he presents as the final answer to all our questions about reality. He makes wild claims about how it is the greatest revelation of all time in all of philosophy, science, and mathematics, and he accuses Academia of intentionally ignoring it.

Now I've tried to read his introduction to it on the link above, but, to be frank, none of it makes any sense to me. I've also tried reading what other people have had to say about it, and most people either seem to ignore it, ridicule it, or claim they don't understand it.

So ... What exactly is he trying to prove? What are his claims and hypotheses? What arguments does he support them with?

Based on his wild claims and some of his ramblings elsewhere (he has said stuff like him being able to prove p = np, or that Trump "obviously" has a very high IQ), I'd normally consider him to be some crank deluded by his own intellect and arrogance, but people tell me that the guy is like really smart, so I am still here trying to understand and give his theory a chance. Can any of you help me out?

Comment: Can’t even bring myself to click this link. It seems like some rather straightforward crankery.

Comment: @JosephWeissman That was my first reaction too. But Cosmos and History published his short [self-summary](http://www.cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/view/618) so I looked. It is not a revelation but not as bad as one might expect, e.g. he notes a problem that enthusiasts of ToE like Tegmark, often gloss:"*in order to qualify as a comprehensive theory of reality, physics must explain itself, its correspondence to reality, and arguably the biological origins and mental activity of physicists in whose minds it exists. In fact, physics as we know it can explain none of these things*

Comment: I cannot imagine how the problem for physics of explaining itself can be 'glossed'. Either the theory is a TOE or it isn't. As for Langan, anyone who claims that their speculative theory represents a revolution in philosophy is dreaming. Perhaps he means a certain area of philosophy. Hell, I suppose I'll have to go look.     .

Comment: PS - I've just read his article on time. It seems he is following Kant and the mystics and seeing space-time as a creation of consciousness. I can't imagine why he thinks this idea is revolutionary. Academics have an unfortunate habit of wanting to brand idea as their own. I find his idea of 'Cosmic time' naive and unworkable but the direction in which he's heading seems to be (what I would say is) the right one. It's all been done, however, and once we start heading in this direction we might as well bypass Langer and go straight to the good stuff.

Comment: High IQ are a crude way to evaluate intelligence; Feynman who is a famous physicist had an above average IQ, but not startling high; if he's making what he feels as new claims but aren't, it's usually because they've missed out on the kind of education that would have been useful to him.

Comment: I had a look at his first essay on his website, and it's not crack-pottery, and he seems to have had a reasonable education; but I'm not sure if he is saying something new.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - I've not read enough of him to have a strong opinion, but as a general point I'd agree with what you say about new claims and missed education.

Comment: Considering how tense discussions about the CTMU can become, I respectfully suggest that the moderators keep a very close eye on this thread. I personally will abstain from commenting any further on this topic as I am very concerned for myself.

Evidence for the claim "CTMU discussions can become very tense" can be found on Quora, Scientopia; and similar discussions of the CTMU on the Internet.

 I personally will abstain from commenting any further on this topic as I am very concerned for myself. I wish everyone the best and hope this conversation is productive.

Comment: I think what Chris Langan was trying to convey is that we should not be trying to describe language with language. Just as, according to Peter Winch, we should not try and describe inference with logical formulas. [That's not how it works](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/78152/47003).

Answer (score 9):

Mostly from skimming over Langan's [summary](http://www.megafoundation.org/CTMU/CTMUnet/CTMU.html) and [paper](http://www.megafoundation.org/CTMU/Articles/Langan_CTMU_092902.pdf) on CTMU,  I'll try to provide a minimal answer primarily about the technical aspects...

CTMU appears to be a layman's attempt at a unifying metaphysical theory of everything.  Stylistically, it's dense, informal, and manifests a severe sort of idiosyncrasy that one tends to see in those who are self-educated or intellectually isolated.

Generally many elements of his theory are reasonably organized and seem to make sense as rehashing, combining and building upon existing (usually complex and not-well-established) ideas.  However, it shows a prominent dearth of formal rigor and citations and is filled with novel and informal thoughts and terminology.  As such, it may be mostly incomprehensible unless you already have a good understanding of the ideas Langan is drawing upon (with little or no citation).  Even then it's often a stretch.  Consider that Wheeler's [*Search for Links*](http://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/wheeler.pdf) has 179 references for 15 pages, while Langan's CTMU has 50 endnotes which contain relatively few references (many of which refer to Wheeler) for 52 pages.

If you're looking for complex eccentric informal philosophy as part of a ToE I think it's alright to try to read some of it.  The sorts of responses you see of ignoring, ridiculing or not understanding it though suggest it may be productive to focus on more traditional sources where possible.

Comment: "Lack of citations" and "no formal rigor" seem like the absolute worst possible reasons for not taking someones ideas seriously. I get that you don't like this guy because he's not in your "club," but you do realize that a significant fraction of all great philosophy is done by these types of outsiders?

Comment: A self-proclaimed "Theory of Everything" should cover everything, including reality itself.  Every mathematical system is self-contained, based on its own assumptions. The "Universe" in a mathematical system is self-defined. But physics is not self-contained.  The first warning flag comes in the first abstract cited below: "perceptual reality (the basis of physics)".  Physics doesn't study "perceptual reality", it's basis is perception *of* reality.  The Venn diagram of reality includes a large Universe and a much smaller perceptual model of it. There is no duality between U and the model.

Comment: @StevenSagona Could you demonstrate you understand why Greg mentioned "lack of citations" and "no formal rigor"? i.e. what would you guess are the best reasons to bring up those things?

Comment: @superiggy, Is this a rhetorical question? Or are you non-rhetorically asking me why I think this other person thinks these things are important? (Why not ask Greg?)

Comment: @StevenSagona Non-rhetorically. It's basic principle of charity practice, to avoid accidentally strawmanning others. It's fine if you are unable or unwilling to do this exercise. Most people aren't.

Comment: @superiggy, not sure how to answer that without just repeating myself then. There is no current working theory to the question of "why does anything exist" -- so expecting that your community of philosophers should be extensively cited is extraordinarily arrogant and likely comes from a psychological desire to pretend as if the community has actually made progress. And therefore there is an expectation of citations to avoid the cognitive dissonance that your community's primary goal hasn't made any progress on probably the most important question in philosophy.

Comment: @StevenSagona I mean there most likely is still some ground work that you take for granted and should cite for reference. But fine even if you created something fundamentally novel, that does not free yourself from formal rigor. At the end of the day your theory still needs to be consistent and readable and not contain formal errors or cover them up by vagueness.

Comment: @haxor789, what "groundwork" has been done for the question: "why do things exist?"?

Comment: I don't know. What does that even mean "why do things exist".

Answer (score 2):

I have to warn younger generations to at least finish college before reading Chris Langan. If kids start dropping out of high school to avoid academics then we’ll have created more social problems than we’ve solved, and it cannot be solved with a eugenics program on the scale of the Manhattan project to build a nuclear weapon to detain citizens or incinerate “the Japs”. Chris was born in 1952 according to Wikipedia, an interesting time of history, so I can forgive some of his way of thinking about Trumpeteerism.

In his Coast to Coast AM Interview he mentions Cramer’s interpretation of quantum mechanics, sub-object classifiers, and how motion is an illusion. He wasn’t at his best during this interview he would say, but I got the gist. One of the predictions he makes is that the universe only seems to be expanding when in fact relative to it, its contents are uniformly contracting. Some of these ideas have been around before separately and implicitly in some form or another. In terms of Tegmark, Langan notes that he mentions mathematical universes but not Topoi, which also seem to unite geometry and logic. There are many different parts to Langan’s ideas, a while back some of us readers tried to organize them on a CTMU Wiki, however I find there comes a point where one needs to refer to other authors, and in Langan’s Cosmos and History he only cites himself thrice, as if he is Hermes Trismegistus the founder of alchemy.

Comment: I can't say I've even heard of Chris Langan whereas I have heard of Tegmark; is he famous in some way?

Comment: *Chris was born in 1952 according to Wikipedia, an interesting time of history, so I can forgive some of his way of thinking about Trumpeteerism.* -- I'm just about that age and I have no idea what you're talking about. Explain please?

Comment: i have yet to pass HS and i am going to read it

Answer (score 2):

I am one of those independent researchers who after reading Ayn Rand’s philosophy as a sophomore in High School found solace in Chris Langan’s writings after a childhood of being brainwashed by Christian cults. I am beholden to nobody and am willing to give credit to Langan, but to also warn people from falling into the trap of the “cult of genius” which throughout history has lent charismatic authority to those with a seed of truth. While I respect the fact that it was developed in isolation, I also think that somewhere he could have cited Goldblatt’s book on topoi at least. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bi-Heyting+topos

Answer (score 1):

"CTMU" stands for the *Cognitive-Theoretic Model of the Universe*. It is a profoundly original theoretical construct which does triple duty as its own universe and model, for which purpose it takes the form of an "intrinsic language" (roughly, a linguistic analogue of intrinsic geometry, which it incorporates as a feature of its universe).

Properly described as metaphysics and thus of universal scope (where metaphysics is properly defined to span all subjects and disciplines along with their content), the CTMU has been the subject of numerous essays and several papers beginning in the late 1980's. The three most recent papers have appeared in the journal *Cosmos & History*.

https://cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/618/1040

https://www.cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/694/1157

https://www.cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/740/1214

The CTMU is unique, significant, and intellectually demanding. Unfortunately, it has also been the subject of unkind remarks by people who seem to know very little of it. (Three things to remember about unkind, underinformed remarks: they're too easy to make, they can make those who issue them appear more knowledgeable and/or intelligent than they actually are, especially where the right sort of derisive language is used, and as a consequence, they are often made for exactly this purpose. Having been publicized by the mass media in connection with the currently unfashionable IQ concept, I've been targeted with them more often than most.)

Note that *Cosmos & History* is a peer reviewed academic journal associated with the group *Foundations of Mind*, informally headquartered at UC Berkeley. Its members include many PhD's in fields ranging from physics, to cognitive science and consciousness studies, to mathematics and philosophy. Some are world-renowned. For what it's worth, we communicate with each other regularly. Within the group, my work is known for uncommon technical sophistication and precision. I'm seldom challenged on technical details.

Please enjoy the papers, and thank you for your interest.

[Note: A paragraph was inadvertently omitted from the first C&H paper. At some point, I'll probably ask the editor to insert it. If you'd like to read an autobiographical interview, I recommend this one:

https://superscholar.org/interviews/christopher-michael-langan/ ]

Comment: If the references supplied will illuminate the OP's explicit questions, no improvements are needed. Else, the inclusion of such references, even if you are the authority, would enhance the value of the answer - it gives people leads on further research. And, welcome to the SE!

Comment: It's a red flag if a theory is not challenged on technical details. Could you provide an example some hard technical detail that could be challenged? I could not find any in "AN INTRODUCTION TO MATHEMATICAL METAPHYSICS".

Comment: Everyone has a definition for "red flag". In my view, circumstantial and ad hominem critiques, of which this site seems to have no shortage, are red flags. Secondly, there are many clearly-stated technical details that can be challenged in every one of my papers and essays. If you deny it, then feel free to post an example of something stated in my papers that is so ambiguous as to defy coherent analysis. (Two other papers were published after those linked: "Introduction to Quantum Metamechanics" and "The Reality Self-Simulation Principle: Reality is a Self-Simulation". They're very precise.)

Comment: Hey Christopher, while I have no issues with you answering questions about your own theory, obviously, I like to raise two problems here: 1) You do not fully answer the question *within this answer*. Mere links are discouraged as they are external to the site and can become dead at some point, thereby impeding the usefulness of the answer. 2) I would like to ask you to mark more clearly that you link and present your own original thoughts and writings (beyond your username), as otherwise, this would fall under our spam policy of promoting oneself without proper disclosure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. A recent comment, critical of me and my work, came up in an email / browser. I clicked the link. I read the critique / question. I posted an answer just under the question itself (editing one's original response to answer such questions is disallowed after 5 minutes). If you have an alternate procedure, please post a link to a clear wording thereof. Thanks.

Comment: This site (which is part of our written rules and basis for moderation) includes both my points in other wording: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion. Also, while comments cannot be edited anymore after 5 minutes, answers can.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it makes sense to read his work, understand the argument, and think about it carefully.

To disagree or agree with someone's position, you must first understand the argument.

And even geniuses start with the ABC's. To understand the CTMU, you must first begin with pre-socratics and end with Chris, otherwise you'll never understand the argument. He's not writing for the laymen, and he's standing on the shoulders of 2500 years of philosophical giants - that is how humanity progresses.

You are trying to go from 0 to 100. Just slow down, take beginner and intermediate classes, read Kant, Hume, Liebniz, Hegel, Locke, Descartes, Plato, and so many others, and then come back to the CTMU later.