# Does Langan think syntax is meaning free isomorphic structures?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-language

Refer: Christopher Langan, "An Introduction to Mathematical Metaphysics", Cosmos and History: The Journal of Natural and Social Philosophy, vol. 13, no. 2, 2017

> Accepting syntax is that part or aspect of the mechanical structure or
>   programming of a computational automaton which enables it to accept or
>   "recognize"  input; the concept can be generalized to non-mechanistic
>   transduction.

Now given that isomorphic content is the 'meaning' conveying, or as Hofstadter has it, the understanding part of language.

**Does Langan see syntax as meaning free, or as conveying meaning on the metaphysical level?**
(And of course if this is a false dichotomy, please explain)

*Bonus: Is there a way to reconcile these views?*

---

**EDIT:**  As Mauro points out the question steps all over the clearly defined distinction between 'semantics' and 'syntax'. The problem comes from the way Langan uses 'syntax' as some kind of *semantic signifier*, that is a pre-inpunt/(information transfer) 'flag' or 'header' that prompts a system to accept isomorphic input from another system.

Comment: Not clear... "[Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) is the set of rules, principles, and processes that govern the structure of sentences in a given language, usually including word order." Form a formal ppoint of view, only well-formed expressions, i.e. syntactically correct ones, have meaning. But meaning is *semantics*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Edit. Any help in getting this clearer would be very welcome.

Comment: Assuming this is the same person, you should try contacting him directly. He apparantly answered a question here before. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47651/what-exactly-is-the-ctmu

Comment: @ChristopherLangan Any illumination?